# Next Occurance of day of next week (Specifically, the next occurance of Wednesday) based on the current date

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals, timestamp

In Oracle SQL Developer, how does one determine the calendar date of the next occurrence of Wednesday, based on the current date.  I have searched and seen many examples for Ruby, PHP, MYSQL, but not for oracle sql.  I read this article about [DATETIME calculations](http://www.sqlmag.com/content1/topic/datetime-calculations-part-3/catpath/tsql3), but these we have not gone over in class.  We are working with date conversion, case, when, timestamps, and intervals but I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nex_day](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions093.htm) function will return the date of the first weekday, specified as the second parameter of the function, later than a date specified as the first parameter of the function. For example:

```
SQL> select next_day(sysdate, 'WEDNESDAY') next_day
  2    from dual
  3  ;

NEXT_DAY
-----------
05-DEC-2012
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE function called NEXT_DAY

Try this

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE,'WEDNESDAY') "Next WED"
  FROM DUAL ;
```